# Missing Code hints for Jest in VS Code IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs, intellisense, macos-sierra

Is there a reason why VS Code on my mac stopped hinting the Jest testing methods? I think it was working before, it works on my Windows 10 for sure. Has anyone encountered the same, maybe I'm missing some config?

Comment: VSCode unexpectedly stops providing IntelliSense sometimes. It works when I reopen the file or restart VSCode

Comment: I know:) but it was working on macbook fine, just this one was a problem on macbook which is not resolved by restarting/reloading of the VSCode.

Comment: you should then file an issue on their github repository. That might help

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela did you figure this out? im havin the same problem that started out of nowhere